# The argument type 'User?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object?>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-futurebuilder

With reference to the recent changes regarding `FirebaseUser` to `User`. `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` is not found at all (while throughing error **"The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked."** 
 The solution to that however was to simply remove the paranthesis as `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`. But now we have another error that it isn't a future type i.e **"The argument type `User` can't be assigned to the parameter type `Future<Object?>?`".** 
 
 Following is my code block.

```
return FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
            builder: (ctx, futureSnapshot) => ListView.builder(
              reverse: true, //  So that 1st message goes to last.
              itemCount: chatDocument.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => MessageBubble(
                message: chatDocument[index]['text'],
                isMe: chatDocument[index]['userId'],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

In the above code block I intend to provide future to my `FutureBuilder`. In summary previously `FirebaseUser` object did return a future, but probably `User` doesn't anymore. How may I handle this case? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to remove FutureBuilder , and use FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser syimply because it is not a Future

Answer (score 1):

I don't typically do that with a FutureBuilder.  Once you have a user, you don't need to async it.

```
final FirebaseAuth_auth = FirebaseAuth.instance();    
final User? user;
user = _auth.currentUser;
```

Then, if user != null ....create your ListView else, return a CircularProgressIndicator or whatever.

Look up Net Ninja for some nice videos for getting yourself set up with all that, just having a stream based on userChanges() for your project.  More robust setup.